# Match Function overwritting everything in R

Tags: r

i have this a DF called Test1 and this is how it looks:

```
Circuit_ID Site_County
001        Yorkshire
002        NA
003        London
004        NA
```

and i have this DF Called FLR

```
Circuit_ID Site_County
001        NA
002        Manchester
003        NA
004        Newcastle
```

What i need to do is fill in the NA values on the Test1 DF without overwritting the values that are already there so this is how i need the Test1 DF to look like:

```
Circuit_ID Site_County
001        Yorkshire
002        Manchester
003        London
004        Newcastle
```

I have written the following code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Test1)) {
if (is.na(Test1$Site_County)) {
    Test1$Site_County = FLR.Cramer.Join[match(Test1$Circuit_ID,
                    FLR.Cramer.Join$Circuit_ID), "Site_County"]
}
else {

  }
}
```

But what the code does is overwrites the whole of the Test1 DF for the data on the FLR DF.
I want to keep which ever data is already on the Site_County col of the Test1 DF and only fill in the NA values with the data from the FLR Site_County DF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that a for loop would not do the trick here so after a sleepless night i managed to get it to work with a simple Ifelse function:

```
Test1$Site_County = ifelse(is.na(Test1$Site_County),
FLR[match(Test1$Circuit_Reference,FLR$Circuit_Reference), "Site_County"], 
as.character(Test1$Site_County))
```

if my code is inefficient please let me know so that i can improve my skills further. Thanks Ken S for your original answer though!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `merge()` for this, while only regarding the cases that do not have `NA`s in `FLR`. Also, by first merging `Test1` with `FLR`, you can afterwards remove any duplicate `Circuit_ID` that have an `NA` in their `Site_County`.

```
rough_df <- merge( Test1, 
                   FLR[complete.cases(FLR$Site_County), ], all=TRUE )
rough_df[!duplicated(rough_df$Circuit_ID), ]
#  Circuit_ID Site_County
#1          1   Yorkshire
#2          2  Manchester
#3          3      London
#4          4   Newcastle
```

Side information on indexing: I used `complete.cases()` and `duplicated()` to index the data frames. Both functions return `TRUE/FALSE` vectors that I like to use to 'select' only those rows/columns that I need.

Comment: does it matter if i have more columns in the DF? i am new to R!

Comment: I'm assuming you'd like to merge all columns, right? I edited the answers a bit to include your question about the columns.

Comment: the Test1 DF has 413 observations and after the merge i only have 360, also, it has dupplicated a column called Company_Name

Comment: That would happen when `Test1 DF` has many `NA` in its `Site_County` column. All rows with `NA` in the `Site_County` column are discarded before merging the two data frames together.

Comment: I reread your question. You should only exclude the incomplete cases for `df2` (or `FLR` in your question). I'll edit

Comment: if there is no match in the FLR DF then i need to keep the NA Value on the Test1 DF. so i should end up with 413 observations no matter what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160089/discussion-between-raul-gonzales-and-ken-s).

Comment: Thanks for your help Ken but it didnt do the trick. i have managed to make it work and i will post the answer. please feel free to improve my code if needed.